# create dropdownlist for a view using form yii framework

Tags: php, yii

im new in yii framework and i want to create a view for a action that use two 
model
this is my controller :

```
  public function actionMoneyRequest()
{
    // important 
    // farz kardam money request meghdare hesabe fardo etebare uno dare az avval @author Masoud
    if(isset($_POST['id']))
    { 
        $model=UserMoneyrequest::model()->findByAttributes(array('userid'=>$this->User()->id,'accountnumberid'=>$_post['id']));
       if(isset($_POST['UserMoneyrequest']))
       {
           if($_POST['amount']<=$model->amount)
           {
               $model->amount=($model->amount-$_POST['amount']);
               $model->save();
           }
           else
           {
               unset($_POST); 
               Yii::app()->user->setFlash('message', 'موجودی حساب کافی نمیباشد.');
               $this->redirect(array(
                       'user/moneyrequest'
               ));
           }
       }
       $this->render('moneyrequest',array(
               'model'=>$model));
    }   
    else
    { 
        $accountnumber=UserAccountnumber::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('userid'=>$this->User()->id));
        $this->render('moneyrequest',array(
                'model'=>$accountnumber
        ));
    }
}
```

at first user have to select his accountnumber from a dropdown list and when he select his Desired account the view show's the selected account information and ... 
and this is my view:

```
<?php
   $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
                                'id'=>'login-form',
                                    'enableClientValidation'=>true,
                                    'clientOptions'=>array(
                                    'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
                                    ),
                                    'htmlOptions'=>array(
                                     'class'=>'js-validation-login form-horizontal push-30-t push-50',
                         )
                          ));
 // var_dump($model); exit;

// var_dump($_POST); exit;
 //$options = array ('12' => 'Twelve', '10' => 'Ten');
 echo $form->dropDownList('useraccountnumber','',array($model->attributes));



   $this->endWidget();


 ?>
```

but i got this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function hasErrors() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\yii\framework\web\helpers\CHtml.php on line 1985

why i got this error ??? 
and when i change this below line:

> echo $form->dropDownList('useraccountnumber','',array());

to:

> echo CHtml::dropDownList('useraccountnumber','',array($model->attributes));

there is no error but i cant see model attributes in dropdown list
how i can to solve this problem and totally how can i use dropdown list with 
define $form? 
i know i have so many mistakes  
thanks everyone for help

Answer (score 0):

The error is related to the fact you don't you th $model   and $accountNumber alternatively each to other. In this situation when you need/use $model your code don't have setted $accountNumber, conversely when you need/use $accountNumber  your code don't have setted $model.

I Think you should rethink your logic. A solution could be render separated view (eg: moneyRequest, moneyByAccount ) each related to the correct variable ...

Comment: thats not true when i edit my controller and send just one model to view i got the same error i want to now how to change       >echo $form->dropDownList('useraccountnumber','',array($model->attributes)); with no errors